# What is the difference between 连续， 陆续， 接连， and 一连？

Tags: meaning, difference

连续
successive; 
continuous; 
consecutive

陆续 
in turn;
successively;
one after the other

接连
on end;
in a row;
in succession

一连
in a row;
in succession;
running

From what I've read, 连续 is the most widespread term and would be the most accurate word for 'continuous', especially in science, as I have a book called 连续时间金融

From examples, 陆续 is closer to 'one after the other' or consecutively

I can't see what's unique about 接连 and 一连 but they seem different from the other two

Comment: there is online information for this type of question, one rough source is http://www.diyifanwen.com/jinyici/jinyici-Y/031522312.htm

Comment: from online information, the key difference between 连续 and 陆续 is that in the former the subject is occurring continuously and in one go and in the latter 'one by one'. I have not been able to find more information on the words 接连 and 一连。 My initial sources are: https://bkrs.info/slovo.php?ch=%E6%8E%A5%E8%BF%9E and https://bkrs.info/slovo.php?ch=%E4%B8%80%E8%BF%9E

Comment: cf。＂汉语８００虚词用法词典＂ **接连**  ［副］running;on end;in a row;in succession;one after the other 一次跟着一次地；一个跟着一个地。后面常有数量词组。１最近接连不断地传来好消息２这个地段连接发生了三起交通事故３我们队接连胜了两场，再胜一场就可以出线了４接连下了三天雨，下得沟满河平５我在中国接连过了四个生日了６她接连给我发了三条短信，邀请我去她家做客７外交部新闻发言人接连发表谈话，阐明中国政府在这个问题上的原则立场８他接连出版了三四部专门研究中国古代经典著作的论著。 
 **一连**  ［副］in a row;in succession 表示动作连续不断或情况连续发生。１去冬今春北京一连下了三场大雪，这是几十年来没有过的２雨一连下了三天三夜，下得沟满河平３因为一连几天的强降雨，造成山体滑坡，出现了泥石流４在电脑前一连坐了五六个小时，觉得头昏眼花的５昨天晚上我一连复习了三个钟头６上星期，我们班一连来了三位新同学７他一连喝了三瓶啤酒，喝得醉醺醺的８星期六晚上，我们俩聊天儿一连聊了三个钟头，夜里两点多才睡９星期天他一连看了四个小时的电视剧光盘１０他在广州一连住了八年，对广州的情况很熟悉。

Comment: **[比较］连连｜一连**   ＂一连＂用在句中，后面常接数量词组。＂连连＂在句中不与数量词组同现。１这雨一连／＊连连下了二十几个小时２昨天我一连／＊连连看了三个电影３今天一连／＊连连接到三封邮件４这届奥运会上他一连／＊连连夺得五块金牌５听了他的建议，大家连连／＊一连点头表示赞同６这场演出太精彩了，观众连连／＊一连鼓掌叫好

Comment: ＂汉语８００虚词用法词典＂ **陆续**  ［副］one after another;in succession 表示动作行为或情况前后相继，时继时续的发生或出现。１一到三月，个种花都陆续开了２今年新招的各国留学生已经陆续到校报道３最近我陆续收到好几封电子邮件，都是向我打听留学信息的４我们公司陆续推出好几种新产品，都受到了消费者的欢迎５夜深了，游客都陆续散去，湖边又恢复了它的宁静６参加中非合作论坛的各国政要已经陆续抵达中国首都北京７中国政府陆续出台了一系列政策，鼓励外国企业来中国投资兴业８为了巩固和发展两国战略伙伴关系，两国领导陆续进行互访和会谈，达成了一系列共识。连／连连／一连，连连／接连／连续，连续／持续／继续，连续／陆续，陆续／接连，陆续／先后／相继 are compared in＂实用汉语近义虚词词典＂more 近义词：屡，屡屡，屡次

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As all four words have very similar meanings, here's an attempt to explain the slight differences:

```
连续 emphasize on the consecutive-ness - there're no breaks in between.
陆续 emphasize on counting - in a sense of 'keep it coming'.
接连 emphasize on succession / connection.  'one after the other' fits here.      
一连 is the same as 连续 but in a sense of shorter range in terms of usage.
```